# XINDY wrongly sorted entries

Tags: indexing, makeindex, xindy

I am testing xindy and have the following problem that the entries for umlauts are wrongly sorted.

Using TeXLive 2021 not full version on Windows.

[image: Example sorting]

MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}

\makeindex[
    options=-L german-din
]     
\begin{document}
    Test
    \index{Äpfel}
    \index{Apfel}
    \index{Test}
    \index{Überflug}
    \index{Öfen }
    \index{Opfer}
    \index{Unfug}
    \printindex
\end{document}
```

The german-din defines this

```
(sort-rule "ä" "ae")
(sort-rule "ö" "oe")
(sort-rule "ü" "ue")

(sort-rule "Ä" "ae")
(sort-rule "Ö" "oe")
(sort-rule "Ü" "ue")
```

so why is Ö and Ü wrongly sorted

Comment: Exactly what LaTeX installation are you on? I get the three umlaut ones listed under O, which seems wrong as well

Comment: I seem to get more appropriate sorting using `-C utf8` for the `xindy` options. (I haven't looked at the sorting rules). With `-C utf8` I get Ä sorted under A, Ö under o and Ü under u

Comment: @daleif I am using texlive on windows.

Comment: Version? I'm using TeLive 2021 on linux

Comment: I am using 2021 too but not the full version.

Comment: I'm running on full, not sure if you're missing something

Comment: I've installed the full version and still having the same issue...

Comment: did you add the extra option I mentioned earlier? Modern LaTeX runs utf8 by default, `xindy` does not

Comment: Yeah.. I found out that if I run `xindy -M texindy -C utf8 -L german-duden filename.idx` the sorting is correct. It seems to be a problem with the command `makeindex[...]`

Comment: Note that I just used `options=-L german-din -C utf8` and made sure to rin with -shell-espace` that worked fine for me.

Comment: The argument `--shell-escape` was missing.... thanks for the help :)